# Encrypted Laravel model feilds do not update

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble updating the `github_oauth_token` and `github_oauth_refresh_token` fields in my `User` model that have the `encrypted` cast. All other fields update fine and the casting is working as expected however the fields will not save to the database.

**User model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Mail\EmailVerification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'email_verification_token',
        'password',
        'github_oauth_token',
        'github_oauth_refresh_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'github_oauth_token' => 'encrypted',
        'github_oauth_refresh_token' => 'encrypted',
    ];

    /**
     * Set the user's github oauth token.
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setGithubOauthTokenAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->github_oauth_token = Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }

    /**
     * Set the user's github oauth refresh token.
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setGithubOauthRefreshTokenAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->github_oauth_refresh_token = Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }
}
```

**User migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name', 45);
            $table->string('last_name', 45);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('email_verification_token', 30)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('github_oauth_token')->nullable();
            $table->string('github_oauth_refresh_token')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**Controller method**

```
public function handleGitHubCallback()
    {
        $gitHubUser = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->github_oauth_token = $gitHubUser->token; // does not update
        $user->github_oauth_refresh_token = $gitHubUser->refreshToken; // does not update
        $user->first_name = 'Johnathan'; // updates fine
        
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('space.list.get')->with('success', Lang::get('messages.success_github_linked'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in `User Model`.You are casting both fields in $cast property

```
 protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'github_oauth_token' => 'encrypted',
        'github_oauth_refresh_token' => 'encrypted',
    ];
```

So no need to add Mutators so remove both below Mutators.

```
public function setGithubOauthTokenAttribute($value)
{
    $this->github_oauth_token = Crypt::encryptString($value);
}

public function setGithubOauthRefreshTokenAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->github_oauth_refresh_token = Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }
```

Also if you want to use mutators then you have an error it should b like below

```
public function setGithubOauthTokenAttribute($value)
    {
          $this->attributes['github_oauth_token ']= Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }

    public function setGithubOauthRefreshTokenAttribute($value)
        {
           $this->attributes['github_oauth_refresh_token ']= Crypt::encryptString($value);
        }
```

Comment: As you suggested I removed the mutators but that didn't work and resulted in the same behaviour. I removed the fields from the casts array and it worked (through the mutators). Ideally, I'd like to just use the encryption cast but it does not seem to be working in my case...

Comment: i have tested both scenario and it works well for me .any one you have to use. Either cast or mutators